# save huge xml from sql to web

Tags: sql-server, xml, asp-classic

In sqlserver I have a function which generates a complex xml of all products with several tables joined: location, suppliers, orders etc.

No problem in that, it runs in 68 sec and produces around 450MB.
It should only be called occationally during migration to another server, so it doesn't matter it takes some time.

I want to make this available for download over webserver.

I've tried some variations of this in classic asp:

```
Response.Buffer = false 
set rs=conn.execute("select cast(dbo.exportXML() as varchar(max)) as res")
response.write rs("res")
```

But I just get a standard

> An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator.
>   If you are the system administrator please click here to find out more about this error.

Not my usual custom 500-errorhandler, so I'm not sure how to find the error.

The problem is in response.write rs("res"), if i just do

```
temp = rs("res")
```

the script runs, but displays nothing of cause; if I then

```
response.write temp
```

I get the same failure.

So the problem is writing such a ling string.

Can I save the file from tsql directly; and run the job periodically from sql agent?

Comment: So you don't actually want to display the XML, you want to send it to the browser as a download?

Comment: Probably downloaded on another server with wget or something. But that's just a header, Not relevant if I not even can't even write the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that there seems to be a limit on how much data can be written at once using Response.Write. The workaround I used was to break the data into chunks like this:

```
Dim Data, Done
Done = False
Do While Not Done
    Data = RecordSet(0).GetChunk(8192)
    If Not Len(Data) = 0 Then
        Response.Write Data
    Else
        Done = True
    End If
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Response.ContentType = "text/xml"    

rs.CursorLocation = 3
rs.Open "select cast(dbo.exportXML() as varchar(max)) as res",conn

'Persist the Recordset in XML format to the ASP Response object. 
'The constant value for adPersistXML is 1.

rs.Save Response, 1
```